# Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{3\sin(x)+2\cos(x)+3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{1}{3\sin(x)+2\cos(x)+3}\ \text{d}x$$
This is one of the question which appeared in my exam today and I tried solving this but just couldn't solve it.
I tried converting sine and cosine in terms of $\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ but didn't help very well..

Does anyone have idea how to evaluate this integral?

Comment: use the tan half angle formulas

Comment: Please explain how the $u=\tan(x/2)$ "didn't help very well". It should.

Comment: after two minutes you know that this will not help?

Comment: see here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Integration_techniques/Tangent_Half_Angle

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. I know that we use this type of substitution for this form of integral, but isn't it too lengthy? I got the answer, but there has to be a shorter method also? Please can you point me towards it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$\int \frac{1}{3\sin x+2\cos x+3}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{1}{3\frac{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}+2\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}+3}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}{\tan^2\frac{x}{2}+6\tan\frac{x}{2}+5}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\sec^2\frac{x}{2}}{\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}+3\right)^2-4}\ dx$$
Let $\tan\frac{x}{2}=t\implies \frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\ dx=dt$
$$=\int \frac{2\ dt}{t^2-4}$$ $$=\frac{2}{4}\ln\left|\frac{t-2}{t+2}\right|+C$$
$$=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\tan\frac{x}{2}-2}{\tan\frac{x}{2}+2}\right|+C}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\int \frac{1}{3\sin(x)+2\cos(x)+3}\text{d}x =$$

---

Substitute $u=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\text{d}x$. Than transform the integrand using the substitutions $\sin(x)=\frac{2u}{u^2+1}$, $\cos(x)=\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}$ and $\text{d}x=\frac{2}{u^2+1}\text{d}u$:

---

$$\int \frac{2}{(u^2+1)\cdot\left(\frac{6u}{u^2+1}+\frac{2(1-u^2)}{u^2+1}+3\right)}\text{d}u =$$
$$\int \frac{2}{u^2+6u+5}\text{d}u =$$
$$2\int \frac{1}{(u+3)^2-4}\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $s=u+3$ and $\text{d}s=\text{d}u$:

---

$$2\int \frac{1}{s^2-4}\text{d}s=$$
$$2\int -\frac{1}{4\left(1-\frac{s^2}{4}\right)}\text{d}s=$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1-\frac{s^2}{4}}\text{d}s=$$

---

Substitute $p=\frac{s}{2}$ and $\text{d}p=\frac{1}{2}\text{d}s$:

---

$$-\int \frac{1}{1-p^2}\text{d}p=$$
$$-\tanh^{-1}(p)+C$$

Substitute everything back and you'll get the final answer!

Comment: Sure you've to substitute everything back

Answer (score 0):

Instead of half-angle sub, recognize $3\sin x+2\cos x=\sqrt{13}\sin t$
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{3\sin x+2\cos x+3}\ dx\\
=& \int \frac1{\sqrt{13}\sin t+3}dt
= \int \frac{\sec^2t\ ( \sqrt{13}\sin t+3) }{\sec^2t\ (\sqrt{13}\sin t+3)^2}dt\\
=& \int \frac{d(\sqrt{13}\sec t+3\tan t)}{(\sqrt{13}\sec t+3\tan t)^2-4}
 =-\frac12\coth^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{13}\sec t+3\tan t}{2}\\
 =& -\frac12\coth^{-1}\frac{{13}\sec x+9\tan x+6}{6-4\tan x}\\
\end{align}